# Installing a network printer twice with different settings

Tags: windows-xp, network-printer

A Windows XP Professional client within a domain has a network printer (HP LaserJet 1320n) with a static IP installed.

The employee told me that previously he had this printer effectively displayed twice - one printer would add a watermark to the sheet, whilst the other printer would leave it untouched. This way he could easily add watermarks simply by choosing a printer accordingly.

How can I install the printer twice in this way? Do I need to download drivers or not since they are already installed?

Comment: Hi Gareth. Please forgive my poor english. I hoped my post was enough clear. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just install it twice, with different descriptive names (like HP_1320n_Watermark and HP_1320_Normal). You can just pick the driver out of the list, and it will ask you if you want to use the same driver, and you will answer yes. You then just change the settings for each printer as you want them.

There is no issue with having two different "logical" printers printing to the same single physical printer.

Another really easy way to do it is to install the printer with any driver you want (if you are not sure what to use), and then once installed, to to Properties>Advanced, and choose the same driver you are using for the printer that is already installed.

If you have any questions as you do it, just post back, but it is easier than you think once you do it.

Comment: +1 Hi KCotreau. Thanks once again for your kindness and your detailed explanation. :) Tomorrow I'll try but knowing your skill I'm sure it will work. I'll come back with a feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the trust :) I've noticed a strange thing: your reputation doesn't change despite upvotes.

Comment: I have gotten the maximum 200 points for the day due to upvotes. In 51 minutes, I can get more. I can get more than 200 due to answers marked as accepted.

Comment: Ah ok. You're an answers machine:) I didn't know that. I often attend stackoverflow and I've never seen this kind of limitation there but I could wrong.

Comment: Hi. I've followed your second advice and everything worked great. Thanks again. Bye ;)

Comment: @eric cartman Glad to help. Thank you again for marking the answer.