# Define the same printer twice with different default settings (Windows)

Tags: windows, printing

Our users would like to install the same networked (via Samba) printer twice and define different default settings (for example one as *color* and the other one as *black and white*.

The users complain that (depending on the driver) they need too many clicks to change the color/BW setting. Choosing among different profile also requires «too many clicks»

Choosing a different printer would allow the users to switch with one click ...

This was possible with Windows XP (see for example [Installing a network printer twice with different settings](https://superuser.com/questions/311678/installing-a-network-printer-twice-with-different-settings)), but does not seem to work with Windows 7 or newer versions.

Is there a way to force windows to install the same device twice?

**Edit** It seems to work with local printers but I was not able to find anything for a networked printer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a copy of a printer in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/250417/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-printer-in-windows-7)

Comment: @duDE For USB attached printers the procedure outlined there doesn't always work. Many USB drivers cause locking issues if both printer-queues try to access the same physical device. My description below only installs 1 print-queue on the USB port. The other queues then use that USB printer as an intermediary via the network.

Comment: "but does not seem to work with Windows 7 or newer versions." It should, what exactly happened when you tried?

Comment: In the control center there is only one copy of the printer. If I configure it again there is still only one printer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit fiddly, but it can be done.
(I do it all the time with Zebra Labelprinters. It's just too much hassle to re-configure the printer-driver each time the label-stock changes. I setup a queue for each type of stock.)

Problem: Windows will often re-initialize locally attached printers (like USB, parallel or even Bonjour based network-printers) on reboot/reconnect, thereby resetting your changes to defaults.

So the trick is to make Windows think it is a network-printer, with the driver and all settings installed locally.
In that case you can make as many "print-queues" as you like that all point to the same network resource.

So if it is a local printer, first install as normal and then "Share" it to create a network print-share. (`\\localhost\printername`).

Now for the special queue's:
For each queue with it's own settings install the printer as a local printer and for the port give `\\localhost\printername`.
(If it really is a networkprinter you usually have to use a TCPIP port for direct printing to the printer. Via a server `\\servername\printer` would most likely be appropriate, but in that case you can setup the queues server-side and have the users just use them as a regular printer-share.)

Unfortunately I don't have a Windows 7 system available to talk you through the exact details.

P.S. This trick works for any Windows version as of XP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, for network printers:

- add printer
- add a local printer
- create new port

  - standard TCP IP
  - set the same IP for that printer but with a different name, like:
    CANON A5
- finish

In the newly created printer, set your custom setting and save.

Now you can use this printer with the different default setting

For USB printers I've tried this process and new printer was made but it doesn't work. I think for USB printers it is not possible.